# issues building an array of arrays jQuery for Laravel4

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, laravel-4

I am submitting an order form which contains fields like client_id, payment_method etc but also the order_items like this: item1(price=12,prod_id=1,quantity=3) ,item2(price=12,prod_id=1,quantity=3) and so on. I would like to submit the form to a laravel 4 API which expects like below:

```
    $data = Input::all();
    $order = Order::create($data);

    if (in_array('items', $data)) {
        $order->items()->attach([$data['items']]);
    }
```

My jQuery looks like below:

```
        $("#submitBtn").on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //lame way - but created 2 forms that I try to join int one array
            var dataArray = $("#neworderform").serializeArray();
            var items = $("#newProdForm").serializeArray();
            var orders = [];
            orders.push(dataArray);
            orders.push(items);
            //submit
            ajaxSubmit(orders);
        })
```

The ajaxSubmit function looks like this:

```
      function ajaxSubmit(orders){

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url : "/orders/save",
            data : orders,

            success : function(data){
                $("#success").html("Order created sucessfully!, redirecting...");

                setInterval(function () {
                    //window.location.href="/ui/orders.html";
                }, 3000);
            },
            error: function(e) {
                $("#success").html(e.message);
            }                
        },"json");

    }
```

When I inspect the console after submitting, I get 2 undefined params(See the image below:):

```
undefined   
undefined
```

[image]

I know the issue lays within the way the array is built but I am not sure how I need to do it (jquery skills I guess) - can somebody help with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what variables are undefined?  Also what function is not reading params

Comment: You have ajaxSubmit(orders) that doesn't exist.  You need a selector to the form.

Comment: Thanks - the ajaxSubmit(orders) function does exist, I have edited the question to add it. I have also added a picture to explain what I mean by params.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way easier way to build the array you wanna build.

Instead of using jquery to do it after the view has rendered, you'd probably be better of building the array before it renders.

In other words build the array in the form input names.

```
<input type="text" name="user[client_id]" ...
```

Now when the form is submitted 'client_id' will be in an array named 'user'. When you do Input::get('user), you will get the entire thing as an array. No need to worry about building one with jquery.

If your inputs require a certain markup which is reusable then I would also recommend using custom form macros to build those, take a look here for that:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#custom-macros

This way of building your input into arrays also comes in very handy when mass assigning form data for storage in a db.

Comment: Thanks Saint Genius, this looks like a good alternative but I am not using blade on the UI.

Comment: Well, if you are not using blade then it is still easier to name your inputs this way. I just referenced blade because it would save you a lot of typing, this solution will work without it though.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise it would work without blade - I will give this a try and get back to you

Comment: This worked to send the array indeed but the backend did bave its own issues which I am changing. Thanks. I will accept this for helping me send the array across